# 3d array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to create a 3d array in javascript, but it is not working.  Can someone help me achieve this?  Here is my code so far...
Feel free to play around with my jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/annhW/1/

```
var myArray = new Array(4);

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    myArray[i] = new Array(3);
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        myArray[j] = new Array(6);
        for (var k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
        myArray[i][j][k] = 'a';
    }
}
}

document.write(myArray[1][2][1]);
```

Comment: "it is not working" -- can you be more specific?

Comment: It doesn't print back anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what "it is not working" means exactly, but your code does have problems because you are reassigning the `myArray` elements. Here's an improvement:

```
var myArray = new Array(4);

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    myArray[i] = new Array(3);
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        myArray[i][j] = new Array(6); // <-- note new subscript
        for (var k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
        myArray[i][j][k] = 'a';
    }
}
}

document.write(myArray[1][2][1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is this line:

```
myArray[j] = new Array(6);
```

Should be

```
myArray[i][j] = new Array(6);
```

If you use a javascript console (either firebug in firefox, or the inspector in chrome / safari), it will throw errors and show you where problems like this are in your code.

Answer (score 0):

When doing second assignment, you are missing the `i` subscript. By doing `myArray[j]` you are overriding what was added outside, effectively still assigning elements in first dimension. Add the second dimension -

`myArray[i][j] = new Array(6);`